# Left() Function to replace text not working

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to have a field consisting of county names to return just the county name. The issue is that the counties import with "Brown County" (example). I want it to just be "Brown". So my goal is to get rid of any part of the county fields that have "County" at the end of the text.

So let me know whats wrong with this update query please - it keeps returning and making all my county fields blank for some reason.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tblImport] SET [tblImport].County = Left([County],Len([County]-7)) " & _
"WHERE ((([tblImport].[County]) Like '*county*'));"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Left([County],Len([County]-7))` with this: `Left([County],Len([County])-7)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a parenthsis problem :

Instead of this :

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tblImport] SET [tblImport].County = Left([County],Len([County]-7)) WHERE ((([tblImport].[County]) Like '*county*'));"
```

try this :

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tblImport] SET [tblImport].County = Left([County],Len([County])-7) WHERE ((([tblImport].[County]) Like '*county*'));"
```

Please note you could also do this if you wish to eradicate only the " county" endings

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tblImport] SET [tblImport].County = Left([County],Len([County])-7) WHERE ((([tblImport].[County]) Like '* county'));"
```